# Динамическое отображение контента через Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Задача - есть класс Task, необходимо отображать и добавлять новые tasks на одной и той же странице при помощи AJAX.

Контроллер:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy

    redirect_to tasks_path
  end

  private
  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

View *views/tasks/index.html.erb*

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>TASK#PAGE</h1>


  <ul id="tasks">
    <%= render @task %>
  </ul>

  <br>


  <%= form_for(@task, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Там же файл *views/tasks/create.js.erb*

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @task) %>").appendTo("#tasks");
```

Партиал `views/tasks/_task.html.er`b содержит следующее:

```
<li><%= task.name %></li>
```

**Проблема - если обновить страницу - все данные содержимого из таблицы tasks исчезают + почему то отображаются только последние добавленные tasks**

Comment: `@tasks = Task.all`; а рендерится это где?

Comment: Рендеринг здесь views/tasks/index.html.erb

Comment: Не вижу там ни одного упоминания `@tasks`.